# How to tell QML XMLHttpRequest to either ignore or use self-signed certificate

Tags: qt, xmlhttprequest, qml

(This is a QML-specific question)
I want to access a REST server at https://localhost:5000 from a QML client *on the same machine* using XMLHttpRequest.

The server works if accessed with a browser, after clicking through a warning about an invalid certificate (it's a self-signed cert.)  However from QML,  `XMLHttpRequest` always fails with no response and status==0.

Note: I control my local machine and know what is listening on port 5000 (it is Interactive Brokers' stand-alone API gateway REST server). I can configure this server to use my own self-signed certificate but can't change much else.  The server does not support http, only https.

**So how can I do the equivalent of accepting the warnings browsers give in this circumstance, but using QML?**

**Alternatively, how can I tell QML to trust my self-signed cert?**

I'm using Qt/qml 6.2.1

```
import QtQuick
Rectangle {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onerror = function() { console.log(`*****onerror called`); }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log(`*****onreadystatechange readyState=${xhr.readyState}`);
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(`==== RESPONSE =====`);
        console.log(`status:${xhr.status}`);
        console.log(`responseURL:${xhr.responseURL}`);
        console.log(`responseText:${xhr.responseText}`);
        console.log(`getAllResponseHeaders():${xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()}`);
        console.log(`===(end)===`);
        Qt.quit();
      }
    };
    //let url = "https://qt.io";  // this works
    let url = "https://localhost:5000/v1/api/sso/validate";
    console.log(`url:${url}`);
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send();

  }
}
```

Output when above is run with `qml`:

```
qml: url:https://localhost:5000/v1/api/sso/validate
qml: *****onreadystatechange readyState=1
qml: *****onreadystatechange readyState=4
qml: ==== RESPONSE =====
qml: status:0
qml: responseURL:undefined
qml: responseText:
qml: getAllResponseHeaders():
qml: ===(end)===
qml: *****onerror called
```

BTW the QML code works fine with other urls with normal certs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no solution within Qt. I solved this in a project by inheriting QQmlWebsocket and overwrite the setSocket function.

```
void MyWebSocket::setSocket(QWebSocket *socket)
{
    connect(socket, &QWebSocket::sslErrors, [socket](const QList<QSslError> &errors){
        if(errors.length() == 1 && errors[0].error() == QSslError::SelfSignedCertificate)  {
            socket->ignoreSslErrors();
        }
    });
    QQmlWebSocket::setSocket(socket);
}
```

This MyWebsocket class should be exported to Qml and used instead of QMLWebsocket.

Answer (score 0):

```
connect(rep, &QNetworkReply::sslErrors, [rep](){ rep->ignoreSslErrors(); });
```

Add the above line to your network request block.  See below for an example post request which uses this.

```
QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("https://www.somewebsite.com"));
QUrlQuery data;
data.addQueryItem("data1", data1);
data.addQueryItem("data2", data2);
req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
auto rep = nam->post(req, data.toString(QUrl::EncodeUnicode | QUrl::EncodeDelimiters | QUrl::EncodeReserved).toUtf8());
connect(rep, &QNetworkReply::sslErrors, [rep](){ rep->ignoreSslErrors(); });
QEventLoop loop;
connect(rep, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec();
QString currentByteArray = rep->readAll();
qDebug() << "network reply" << currentByteArray;
rep->deleteLater();
```